# Doing saturation aritmetic with atomics

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I've been looking around for a way to protect an integer to be incremented atomically **but** with bound checking.
*I've looked around for other posts but none seem to have a good solution (and some are pre-C++11).*

What I need is a library like the following:

```
class bounded_atomic_uint
{
    private:
    uint32_t ctr;
    uint32_t max;
    mutex mtx;

    public:
    bounded_atomic_uint(uint32_t max = UINT32_MAX) : ctr(0), max(max) {}
    ~bounded_atomic_uint() = default;
    // make in uncopyable and un-movable
    bounded_atomic_uint(bounded_atomic_uint&&) = delete;
    bounded_atomic_uint& operator=(bounded_atomic_uint&&) = delete;

    bool inc();
    bool dec();
    uint32_t get();
};

bool bounded_atomic_uint::inc() {
    lock_guard<mutex> lck (mtx);
    if (ctr < max) {
        ctr++;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "max reached (" << max << ")" << endl; // to be removed!
        return false; // reached max value
    }
}

bool bounded_atomic_uint::dec() {
    lock_guard<mutex> lck (mtx);
    if (ctr > 0) {
        ctr--;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        cout << "min reached (0)" << endl; // to be removed!
        return false; // reached min value
    }
}

uint32_t bounded_atomic_uint::get() {
    lock_guard<mutex> lck (mtx);
    return ctr;
}
```

to be used like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    bounded_atomic_uint val(3);

    if (val.dec())
        cout << "error: dec from 0 succeeded !!" << endl;
    cout << val.get() << endl; // make sure it prints 0
    val.inc();
    val.inc();
    cout << val.get() << endl;
    if (!val.inc())
        cout << "error: havent reached max but failed!!" << endl;

    if (val.inc())
        cout << "error max not detected!!" << endl;

    cout << val.get() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any easier way (or more correct) of doing this?
Neither std::atomic nor boost::atomic seem to have a way to avoid out-bounding check (inside a lock).

If not, is this *simplistic* class good enough?
Or am I missing anything here?

**Note** that the *couts* on the library are to be removed on real usage!

Comment: FYI the term you are looking for is "saturation arithmetic".

Answer (score 4):

The is-there-a-library-that-does-this part of your question [is off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question), so let me instead answer the how-can-we-implement-this question, which is on-topic and quite interesting.

Let's start by removing the lock from your example and replacing the plain `int`s with [`atomic`s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic):

```
class bounded_atomic_uint
{
    private:
    atomic<uint32_t> ctr;
    uint32_t max;

    public:
    bounded_atomic_uint(uint32_t max = UINT32_MAX) : ctr(0), max(max) {}
    ~bounded_atomic_uint() = default;
    // make in uncopyable and un-movable
    bounded_atomic_uint(bounded_atomic_uint&&) = delete;
    bounded_atomic_uint& operator=(bounded_atomic_uint&&) = delete;

    bool inc();
    bool dec();
    uint32_t get();
};

bool bounded_atomic_uint::inc() {
    if (ctr < max) {
        ctr++;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "max reached (" << max << ")" << endl; // to be removed!
        return false; // reached max value
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that, in between the bounds-check and the increment, the value could have changed. So you can only guarantee that you do not break the bounds in absence of contention.

You can easily fix this by ensuring upon increment that the value did not change in between. This is exactly what [`compare_exchange`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) provides:

```
bool bounded_atomic_uint::inc() {
    while(true) {
        auto ctr_old = ctr.load();
        if (ctr_old < max) {
            if(ctr.compare_exchange_weak(ctr_old, ctr_old + 1)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "max reached (" << max << ")" << endl; // to be removed!
            return false; // reached max value
        }
    }
}
```

Now if the counter changes between the bounds check and the writing of the increment, `compare_exchange_weak` will fail, so we have to try again. If the number exceeded the bounds in the meantime, we will detect this in the next loop iteration and exit accordingly. Note that if you ignore spurious failures* of `compare_exchange`, you will only ever have to loop if there was an actual concurrent write to the atomic, so this implementation is actually [*lock-free*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm#Lock-freedom).

We can make this slightly more efficient by factoring the repeated loading of the atomic into the `compare_exchange` (remember that `compare_exchange` writes the actual value of the atomic back to the first argument):

```
bool bounded_atomic_uint::inc() {
    auto ctr_old = ctr.load();
    do {
        if (ctr_old >= max) {
            cout << "max reached (" << max << ")" << endl; // to be removed!
            return false; // reached max value
        }
    } while(!ctr.compare_exchange_weak(ctr_old, ctr_old + 1));
    return true;
}
```

<sub>*We could get rid of the spurious failures by using `compare_exchange_strong` instead, but since we have to loop anyway, there is actually no good reason for doing that here.</sub>

Comment: Thx for the answer. My understanding is that `atomics` are not lock-free guaranteed. In the cases where the implementation is actually lock-free this is a much better solution in fact (though uglier :P), but in the case atomic are going to be synchronized, this solution will required at least the lock to be acquired twice (one for `load()` and another for the `compare_exchange()`), isn't it?

Comment: @Pacheco -- on any reasonable hardware atomic operations will be lock-free. If you're worried, use `atomic_is_lock_free` to check.

Comment: @Pacheco First off, please note that the *lock* part in lock-free programming [does not refer to a literal lock (like a mutex)](http://preshing.com/20120612/an-introduction-to-lock-free-programming/). Second, the fact that we access the atomic twice is countered by the fact that we only access it for the smallest amount of time necessary, which could boost throughput of the overall system significantly. It could also have the opposite effect. The only way to be sure is to try both and measure on the desired target platform. Yes, multithreading is hard...